# How to resize and image before saving it with gridfs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, multer, gridfs, sharp

i'm a beginner with mongoDB and gridfs. I have a code which save in the database an incoming image. But I'd like to resize the image before saving it. It tried to use sharp, but I don't really understand how it works.

I tried the following code, but it's not working

```
const storage = new GridFsStorage({
  url: mongoURI,

  file: (req, file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const filename = req.params.userID;
      const fileInfo = {
        filename: filename,
        bucketName: "ProfilePic", 
      };
      resolve(fileInfo);
    });
  }
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

router.post("/setProfilePic/:userID", upload.single("picture"), async(req, res) => {
//code not working
  await sharp(req.file.path)
    .resize(500)
    .jpeg({quality: 50})
    .toFile(
        path.resolve(req.file.destination,'resized',image)
    )
// end of non working code
  return res.status(200).json({state: "ok"})
});
```

Comment: sharp is probably throwing an error. Can you surround the `await` with a `try..catch` block and log the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution is to use the `fromStream` method from `'multer-gridfs-storage'`

The idea goes like this:

1. Use `multer` to parse the file, get the file buffer (raw data)
2. Use `sharp` to catch the input buffer and create another buffer that contains the resized image.
3. Use `Readable` to create a readable stream, then apply `fromStream` method to pipe the stream to the database.

---

Implementation

```
const multer = require('multer')
const { GridFsStorage } = require("multer-gridfs-storage");
const { Readable } = require("stream"); // from nodejs
const sharp = require("sharp");

const storage = new GridFsStorage({
  url: mongoURI,
  options: { useUnifiedTopology: true }, // silence the warning
  file: () => ({ bucketName: "ProfilePic",filename: req.params.userID }),
});

router.post("/setProfilePic/:userID",multer().single('picture'),(req,res) => {
  const file = req.file
  const buffer = file.buffer

  // chain sharp methods
  sharp(buffer)
    .resize(500)
    .jpeg({ quality: 50 })
    .toBuffer((err, data, info) => {

      // data here directly contains the buffer object.
      const fileStream = Readable.from(data);

      // write the resized stream to the database.
      storage.fromStream(fileStream, req, file).then(() => {
        res.json({ state: 'ok' });
      });
    });
})
```

---

Instead of making full use of the multer's storage engine, I create my own stream.

I am also a MongoDB beginner, so I am happy enough to make it work. If it doesn't work, please leave a comment and I will try my best to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I used the previous answer. I made a few changes to make it work. My req.file.buffer was always undefined. So I made few changes.

There are two things I want to highlight below

1. Make sure you use multer version "^2.0.0-rc.1".
2. You can create buffer by

```
const buffer = await getStream.buffer(req.file.stream);
```

rest of solution is exactly same. Here is the full code sample.

```
const multer = require('multer')
const { GridFsStorage } = require("multer-gridfs-storage");
const { Readable } = require("stream"); // from nodejs
const sharp = require("sharp");
const getStream = require("get-stream");

const storage = new GridFsStorage({
  url: mongoURI,
  options: { useUnifiedTopology: true }, // silence the warning
  file: () => ({ bucketName: "ProfilePic",filename: req.params.userID }),
});

app.post("/setProfilePic/:userID", multer.single("image"), async (req, res) => {
  const file = req.file;
  const buffer = await getStream.buffer(req.file.stream);

  // chain sharp methods

  sharp(buffer)
    .resize(200, 100)
    .jpeg({ quality: 50 })
    .toBuffer((err, data, info) => {
      // data here directly contains the buffer object.
      const fileStream = Readable.from(data);

      // write the resized stream to the database.
      storage.fromStream(fileStream, req, file).then(() => {
        res.json({ state: "ok" });
      });
    });
});
```